# How to build a minimal Ubuntu from a Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 12.04

I have tried the minimal Ubuntu installation, but the disk space it occupies is still a bit large, I want to tailor it, for example: it contains systemd, bash, basic packages and so on. Is there a way to build a minimal system from an existing Ubuntu, or some other way?

Thank you！

Comment: You've tagged a off-topic release (12.04 LTS is EOL, and 12.04 ESM is off-topic as supported elsewhere).   Also the minimal-installation options install the same packages, they have a list of packages to remove post-installation (of everything & before user is told installation is completed).  You could add other packages to the list-of-remove packages that make up the minimal-installation option.

Comment: You could try netinstall or server images from there https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads. You`ll be prompted what services to install, just choose nothing, to keep system minimal.

Comment: "Is there a way to build a minimal system from an existing Ubuntu, or some other way?"  You still need the space to do that. The mini.iso should be of footprint of less than 60Mb.So what do you consider "a bit large"?

Comment: I installed ubuntu16.04 with ubuntu-server-minimal.seed, which takes up 800MB of disk space.
Does the disk space take up less than this when using mini.iso? I tried, my server can't access the network using mini.iso. Is there a way to install it locally using mini.iso.